# Laravel submitting blank form

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm receiving the following error when submitting a blank form in Laravel 4.

> Undefined index: fields

There are currently no issues outside of Laravel. Users should be able to submit the form even without selections.

I can certainly check if isset and act accordingly but just wondering if it's something noticeable with Laravel.

```
$submission = $_POST['fields'];
```

Form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'results')) }}
  <table>            
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>text 1</span>
           {{ Form::checkbox('fields[]', 'value_1', false, array('class'=>'checkbox_style'))  }} 
        </td>
        <td><span>text 2</span>
           {{ Form::checkbox('fields[]', 'value_2', false, array('class'=>'checkbox_style'))  }}
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  {{  Form::submit('Submit', array('class'=>'btn'))  }}
{{  Form::close()  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good practice to double check variables that could be empty or undefined.

```php
$submission = empty($_POST['fields']) ? $_POST['fields'] : [];
```

This way if `$_POST['fields']` would be undefined, it will be set to an empty array.

Comment: That was my plan, but I was wondering why Laravel throws the error. While outside of Laravel it's considered an empty array and no issues arise.

Comment: It doesn't know this is supposed to be an array, because you're checking on the key `'fields'`, not on `$_POST` itself